# xamarin forms list view draw cells but they are empty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

[The listview shows the correct number of ideas in the database, but the label won't show idea names like the wfa does.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmUiQ.png)

The label in my datatemplate is bound to the idea name variable. For some reason it doesn't seem to write the name of these ideas in the viewcell's label.

I know this isn't a problem with my sql code, since it works perfectly fine in the wfa.

Steps I used to find a solution to my problem:
    1. researched about the listview, how it works and how to use it
    2. I spent 4 hours messing around trying to bind the label in multiple ways
    3. the label won't bind to my variables even out of the list view.
    4. I searched for a solution on google going 2 pages in for every search term i could think of.

here's the code the idea list depends on:

The Ideas listview

```
<ListView x:Name="Ideas" SeparatorColor="Accent" SeparatorVisibility="Default" ItemsSource="{Binding idea}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Bisque" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                        <Label Text="{Binding idea.idea}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="Small"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The Mainpage class (simplified to only show the code used by the listview)

```
Class Mainpage {
public static bool ShowHiddenIdeas = false;

ListView ideaso;

public static List<Idea> ideas;

public MainPage() {
    GetIdeas(0); //get all ideas from the first table in the database 
    InitializeComponent();
}

void GetIdeas(int id) {
ideas = Kaiosql.GetIdeaSQL(id); //reads from the database and compiles a list of ideas in the table

/* 
tried using a list of strings instead of the idea class
List<string> ideasz = new List<string>();
    foreach (Idea i in ideas)
    {
        ideasz.Add(i.idea);
    } 
It just does the same thing
*/

ideaso.ItemsSource = ideas;
}
}
```

the Idea class

```
public class Idea
{
    public int ID;
    public string idea;
    public string Description;
    public string Type;
    public string Time;
    public bool HasFolder;
    public string FolderPath;
    public bool IsStarted;
    public bool IsComplete;
    public bool IsUploaded;

    public Idea(int iD, string idea, string description, string type, string time, bool hasFolder = false, string folderPath = null, bool isStarted = false, bool isComplete = false, bool isUploaded = false)
    {
        ID = iD;
        this.idea = idea;
        Description = description;
        Type = type;
        Time = time;
        HasFolder = hasFolder;
        FolderPath = folderPath;
        IsStarted = isStarted;
        IsComplete = isComplete;
        IsUploaded = isUploaded;
    }
}
```

The class has more information than my ideabase currently can output. I hope this isn't the reason the data doesn't show up.

Much Thanks! - Zak Kaioken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work you need to do a few changes.

First one and very important. Your `Idea` class needs to be modified to used `Properties` instead of public `fields` for this you will need to add **getters** and **setters** like this:

```
public class Idea
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string idea {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string Time {get; set;}
    public bool HasFolder {get; set;}
    public string FolderPath {get; set;}
    public bool IsStarted {get; set;}
    public bool IsComplete {get; set;}
    public bool IsUploaded {get; set;}

    public Idea(int iD, string idea, string description, string type, string time, bool hasFolder = false, string folderPath = null, bool isStarted = false, bool isComplete = false, bool isUploaded = false)
    {
        ID = iD;
        this.idea = idea;
        Description = description;
        Type = type;
        Time = time;
        HasFolder = hasFolder;
        FolderPath = folderPath;
        IsStarted = isStarted;
        IsComplete = isComplete;
        IsUploaded = isUploaded;
    }
}
```

Without this change you will **not** be able to see the text in the list since the binding requires it.

Second: This could be a typo since it will definitely not run like this.

change:

`ideaso.ItemsSource = ideas;`

for

`Ideas.ItemsSource = ideas;`

Being Ideas the x:Name assigned the ListView in the XAML.

Third: Change the order of the calls in the Constructor.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetIdeas(0); //get all ideas from the first table in the database 
}
```

The `GetIdeas` method will try to access the ListView and this one is instantiated when the `InitializeComponent` method is called. This is why is mandatory calling this method before attempting to access any UIElement on the XAML.

Four:

The XAML should look like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Ideas" SeparatorColor="Accent" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Bisque" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                    <Label Text="{Binding idea}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="Small"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Remove the extra "ideas" on the text binding and Remove the **ItemSource** as you are already setting this property in the code behind.

With these changes you should see the list with your `ideas`.

There are other changes you could do to make your code a little more MVVM-ish, you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I think it was the getters and setters, as well as putting the functions before the initialization! And right now I'm not focusing on optimizing the code. I just got started with the cross platform forms, and I don't really know my way around.

Comment: great it worked. There's a lot to learn, just try to learn one thing at the time and you will definitely succeed.- @ZakKaioken

Comment: I did not change the ideaso to Ideas because I reference them with these  "ListView ideaso;" and "ideaso = Ideas;" which lets me change the variables in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many idea. Here is what your xaml should look like

**EDIT**

[Try this link](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)

```
<ListView x:Name="Ideas" SeparatorColor="Accent" SeparatorVisibility="Default" ItemsSource="{Binding idea}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Bisque" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                        <Label Text="{Binding idea}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="Small"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: That doesnt work.  I changed it to idea.idea to test if it was because i was referencing the list of ideas instead of the idea. It was a really last minute change. thanks for catching it though.

Comment: The item template displays the properties of one of the item source if you have a list of items and it has a variable called item then you just put items. Or do you have ideas[0].idea.idea

Comment: That makes sense. I just dont know how to bind it like that. could I be missing something that binds them?